# Access to azure cosmos db through specific public ip address only

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, firewall

I want to access cosmos db through specific ip address only. The only way I can see to achieve this is, specifying that ip address in 'Firewall and Virtual Network' section of azure cosmos db. Is there any other way to achieve this without specifying ip address in firewall ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP Firewall is the right way to do this. Is there a reason why you don't want to use IP Firewall?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to avoid an extra step to mention ips in firewall. I have already used "Azure Private Link" and Virtual Network and was wondering if these options can cover the scenario to restrict public ip too. But if thats the only way, I am more than happy to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure Azure Private Link.It is a set of private IP addresses in a subnet within your virtual network. You can then limit access to an Azure Cosmos account over private IP addresses.More details,please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-private-endpoints).

By the way,you can use **User** + **Permission** to limit users accessing the resources.

Comment: Even if I use Azure Private Link, still I need to specify public ip addresses in firewall.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-private-endpoints#blocking-public-network-access-during-account-creation